# C Insert Element Into List At Given Index

Tags: c, list, insert, element

I have a programming question in C where I am trying to design a List and add an element at a given index.

Here is my insertElement method:

```
ListElement* getNextElement(ListElement *listElement){
    return listElement->nextElement;
}

 /* Insert a given element at the specified index in a specified list. Shifts
 *  all other elements to the right, increasing their index by 1. 
 *  Requires 0 <= index <= listSize(), otherwise the element should not be inserted.  
 */
void insertElement(List *list, ListElement *listElement, int index) {
    ListElement* tempElement = list->headElement;
    int count = 0;
    while (tempElement != NULL) {
        if (count == index) {
        }
        tempElement = getNextElement(tempElement);
        count++;
    }
}
```

But I don't actually know how to shift over and insert the element.

Here is how I attempt to insert:

```
int main() {
    ListElement* newElement = malloc(sizeof(ListElement));
    insertElement(&myList, newElement, 1);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: index and list sounds strange. Matthew gives you some tips

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of a linked list is that, unlike an array, you don't need to shift or move anything in order to do an insert.

Assume your list is `A->C` and you want to insert `B` after `A` to give `A->B->C`.

- `A->nextElement` is set to `C`; that needs to change.
- `B->nextElement` is not set; that needs to change.

You should be able to see how to accomplish that with what you're given.

Comment: if (count == (index - 1)) {
   setNextElement(listElement);
  } Something like that? The only issue is I do not know how to set listElement's next element to be the second element after the one I'm currently on. If that makes any sense..

Comment: @Nic `listElement->nextElement = tempElement->nextElement; tempElement->nextElement = listElement;`.  In my example, that works out to `B->next = A->next; A->next = B;` which is equivalent to `B->next = C; A->next = B;`

Comment: Hmm, I get some interesting output. The function adds the element, but it seems to add the pointer address.  LIST: 8, 9, 10, 11, 12                                           after add 
LIST: 8, 9, 135364624, 10, 11, 12